# Ternary operator adding to dictionary<string, list<uri>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, ternary-operator

How could use the ternary operator in MVC C# to make this check if empty add to list else create new list logic shorter for a dictionary>?

```
            if (urlDictionary.ContainsKey(url.Authority))
            {
                urlDictionary[url.Authority].Add(url);
            }
            else
            {
                urlDictionary.Add(url.Authority, new List<Uri> { url });
            }
```

Comment: I recommend using `EditableLookup` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/JonSkeet.MiscUtil/.  That provides a nicer multimap interface by design.  `Dictionary<T, List<U>>` is a hack that exposes the inner `List<U>`, which is an implementation detail best hidden from the consumer.

Comment: @mjwills my guess is he figured out ten seconds after posting the question "oh, I can just make this a function instead of repeating it everywhere" (bonus points for extension method), and any answer thus became far less important and he's forgotten this post entirely.

Comment: @DaxFohl I'm not sure what that function would look like. It would have to return a dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use the ternary operator where an expression is expected. This means you can for example assign a value to a variable based on a boolean condition with the operator.

```
var a = myCondition ? 1 : 0;
```

Also you can use the operator to pass a value as a parameter of a method:

```
DoSomething(myCondition ? 1 : 0);
```

However you can *not* call a method based on an boolean expression:

```
myCondition ? list.Add(myValue) : list.Add(new MyValue());
```

This will produce a compiler-error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Furthermore you have different types for what you provide to the `Add`-method. On the left side of the operator you add a single item whereas on the right side you're adding a new list.

Use a simple if instead:

```
if (!urlDictionary.ContainsKey(url.Authority))
    urlDictionary[url.Authority] = new List<Uri>();

urlDictionary[url.Authority].Add(url);
```

Comment: You do not need to use the *conditional* operator as a part of an assignment expression.  You can use it in any situation where a value is expected.

Answer (score 5):

#### Option 1

I would suggest this approach. `TryGetValue` allows you to check for an existence of a Key **and return the matching value at the same time**.

```
List<Uri> list = null;
if (!urlDictionary.TryGetValue(url.Authority, out list))
{ 
    list = new List<Uri>();
    urlDictionary[url.Authority] = list;
}
list.Add(url);
```

*`ContainsKey` should generally not be used in this kind of situation, since it will mean multiple (unnecessary) hash lookups if the key does exist.*

#### Option 2

If you are willing to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` (which will be slower) then you can simplify the code down to a single call to `AddOrUpdate`:

```
urlDictionary.AddOrUpdate(url.Authority,
    (key) => new List<Uri>() { url },
    (key, oldValue) =>
        {
            oldValue.Add(url);
            return oldValue;
        });
```

#### Option 3

A possible third approach is to avoid the `if` condition altogether and use [`MultiValueDictionary`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/) (which allows you to have multiple values for the same key - the same as your existing `Dictionary` but without you having to [explicitly handle the `List` yourself](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/)):

```
var urlDictionary = new MultiValueDictionary<string, Uri>();
urlDictionary.Add(url.Authority, url);
```

Comment: "since it will mean multiple (unnecessary) hash lookups if the key does exist" That won´t matter that much, as a hash-based map is incredibly fast just *because* it uses hashes.

Comment: Sure, but doing something twice is (by definition) slower than doing it once.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar scenario and achieved it as below to reduce the lines of code

```
var dictValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictValues.Add("ValueofX", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueX) ? valueX : string.Empty);
dictValues.Add("ValueofY", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueY) ? valueY : string.Empty);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you *have* to use the conditional operator, below is the way it would be done.  As noted in the comments it is not performance optimized, however hash lookups are ~10ns, so unless this is in a tight loop of millions of iterations, it will make no tangible difference.

```
urlDictionary[url.Authority] = (urlDictionary.ContainsKey(url.Authority)
                                         ? urlDictionary[url.Authority]
                                         : new List<Uri>())
                                                           .Add(url);
```

My recommendation however would be to use `EditableLookup` from Jon Skeet's old [MiscUtil](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/) library.  That way you hide the inner `List<T>`, which is an implementation detail, and get a more consistent interface to what you would expect from a multimap.

Comment: If the key exists, this will have **two** hash lookups and then an unnecessary write operation.

Comment: @mjwills Why three? `ContainsKey` does one, and setting the value does a second. The assignment will *not* make a read-op on the map.

Comment: Updated for clarity @HimBromBeere .

Comment: @HimBromBeere True, but a write operation requires determining if the value already exists, which requires inherently doing just as much work (and sometimes more, if the value doesn't exist and needs to be added, which isn't the case in that situation).

Comment: @mjwills Updated answer to reflect this.  However the question specifically asked for a solution using a ternary operator, in both the title and description.  Optimizing performance was never mentioned as a concern.

Comment: @mjwills Updated code to include a fourth hash lookup, just for style points. :)  (and to save a line of code)

Comment: I know you are being facetious, but `(urlDictionary[url.Authority] = urlDictionary.ContainsKey(url.Authority)
                ? urlDictionary[url.Authority]
                : new List<Uri>()).Add(url);` could be used to avoid one of the lookups.

Comment: @mjwills Totally not being facetious.  Totally just finished an 8-pack of Guinness.  Kinda being facetious I guess.  But you're right *and* it makes a one-line expression....